# Some product images are not showing in magento

Tags: php, magento

I recently migrated my `magento` website to a different server, and here's the process I used:

1. Remove .htaccess folder from media folder .
2. rebuild all indexes as well as flush cache in the administration area.
3. php memory size is 512M.

Same Copy of website working fine in my `localhost` and different server, I am very confused what step I have to take please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You missed several steps. Process of migrating `Magento` from local to live is

1. Upload all files to server
2. clear `var/cache` and `var/session` folder
3. Update live `URL` in `core_config` table `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`.
4. Empty `log_url` table
5. Reindexing

Still you are getting issues. Check `exception.log` and `system.log` in `var/log` folder.

Comment: Thanks For Your Reply ,

Comment: I did all step that you tell but some of product images are not loaded.

Comment: Check `exception.log` and `system.log` in `var/log folder`.

Comment: There are only one file system.log in log folder and that that display error  :-------                                                                                                                                                 2016-04-22T15:27:04+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: require_once(/home/partsppd/public_html/errors/report.php) [<a href='function.require-once'>function.require-once</a>]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /home/partsppd/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 925

Comment: there might be two things causing this issue 1. Permission issues 2. `file/folders` are not uploaded properly. reset permission of all `files/folders`  and your site if any file is missing. As per current error you do not have `report.php`. this might be causing the issue

Comment: is report.php responsible for the issues .

Comment: might be. but main issue is permission